# What is this Luftwaffe branded plane at Tirana's airport?

Tags: aircraft-identification

The question is pretty much in the title, I was definitely not expecting to see a Luftwaffe branded plane, so I'm curious to know what I'm looking at! At the time of posting the plane is sitting at Tirana's international airport

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Transport_Wing_(German_Air_Force)#Current_Fleet (I was expecting an executive aircraft, but instead is usually not used for government transportation). Wild guess: UN forces, or maybe a change of crew on an army ship in a nearby port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aircraft **15+11** is an **Airbus A321LR** (the long range variant of the A321neo) operated by the German Air Force (Luftwaffe) as a troop transporter and MedEvac plane:

> The Air Force has taken delivery of the second Airbus A321LR from Lufthansa Technik in Hamburg. The aircraft with the tactical identification 15+11 will soon be available to the emergency services for troop transport and parliamentary flight operations - and will be given another task in 2023.
>
> The 15+10 is followed by the 15+11: Germany has two state-of-the-art A321LRs for special Air Force tasks. Starting next year, both aircraft will also be equipped for medical transport and evacuation flights (MedEvac).

<sup>([aero.de News](https://www.aero.de/news-43337/Luftwaffe-hat-jetzt-ein-A321LR-Duo.html), 2022-08-19, in German, translated by Google)</sup>

It arrived in Tirana yesterday evening from Frankfurt:

[image: FlightAware Screenshot]
<sup>([flightaware.com](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/1511))</sup>

The flight was probably for the German Foreign Minister and her delegation who [arrived in Tirana yesterday](https://www.rtklive.com/en/news-single.php?ID=24640) to discuss the recent tensions between Kosovo and Serbia (thanks to @DeltaLima for the link).

Comment: From [this article](https://www.euractiv.com/section/politics/news/eu-measures-against-serbia-set-to-be-on-agenda-in-tirana-fms-meeting/), I infer that the [German minister of foreign affairs is visiting Tirana](https://www.rtklive.com/en/news-single.php?ID=24640) . It's very likely she was on that Lufwaffe aircraft.

Comment: @DeltaLima Yeah, that's probably the reason. She is usually using one of the executive jets (white livery), but then again the German Air Force isn't exactly known for their reliability, so maybe this was the only one available xD